# Dev express filter row drop down

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a filter row on a Grid View and I need to find a way to populate the drop down list so that I can use the drop down list.

The Dev Express website achieves this through binding it to a data scource on the page, I need to find a way to do this but through the code behind.

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Filtering/FilterRow.aspx

If you could point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Many thanks

Comment: I have found much use out of the GenericDataSource control...

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to handle the **ASPxGridView.AutoFilterCellEditorInitialize** event to initialize an individual AutoFilterRow's editor manually.

Please check the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q302836 Support Center ticket regarding this.